# Constructor xml doc in F#?

Tags: f#

How do you attach xml documentation (you know, the /// kind) to constructors in F#? I'm not surprised that I haven't managed to figure it out for implicit constructors... but I can't even get it to work for explicit constructors. It works fine for the class itself and other members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug (you're right, it does not work).  When Beta2 ships, this bug is likely to still be present, but hopefully it will be fixed for the final release of VS2010.

Comment: Thanks. That's all good to know.
I could not find any documentation anywhere showing how one would attach XML documentation to the implicit constructor. If possible, would you amend your answer with that syntax, just for posterity's sake?

Comment: There is no syntax for it (we have a suggestion to support it, but may release without it).  Note that you can work around this by creating a private implicit constructor that takes an extra dummy parameter (e.g. of type 'unit'), and then make what-was-originally-the-implicit-constructor explicit and xmldoc it that way.